# all pairs of a and b in an equation containing gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Find all pairs of positive integers $a,b$ such that 
$$ab=160+ 90\cdot \gcd(a,b)$$
how do we approach this type of problem in number theory or what is the best way to solve this  ?Here gcd is greatest common divisor .

Answer (score 1):

Put $d=\gcd(a,b),a=md,b=nd$ so we have $mnd^2-90d-160=0$. Hence $d$ divides 160. If 5 divides $d$, then 25 divides 160, contradiction. So $d=1,2,4,8,16$ or 32.

If $d=1$, then $mn=250=2\cdot5^3$, but $m,n$ are coprime, so $a,b$ are $1,250$ or $2,125$. If $d=2$, then $mn=85$, so $a,b$ are $2,170$ or $10,34$.

If $d=4$, then 16 divides 360, contradiction. If $d=8$ then 64 divides 880, contradiction. If $d=16$, then 256 divides 1600, contradiction. If $d=32$, then $32^2$ divides 3040. Contradiction.

Comment: can you explain it more clearly taking an example?

Comment: @satya Which part is unclear?

Comment: Hence d divides 160. If 5 divides d, then 25 divides 160, contradiction. So d=1,2,4,8,16 or 32.

Comment: We have $mnd^2-90d=160$, so $160=d(mnd-90)$. Hence $d$ and $mnd-90$ must be factors of 160.

Comment: the factor part was clear but i am not getting why you considered 5 divides 160  and then taking 25 doesn't ?

Comment: Sorry. $90d$ has an additional factor of 5: $90d=18\cdot5\cdot d$, so $25$ divides $mnd^2$ and $90d$, so it must divide 160.